# how to modularize ember.js templates?

Tags: ember.js

all the examples on ember.js show templates being used in the form of inline script tags within a single large html file.
Is there any way to separate the templates in files of their own and if so what are the best practices around it?

Comment: what is your server backend?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're focussing here on re-structuring the front-end application and defining a  workflow for the javascript environment (ember.js and its dependencies) there are various tools that allow you to do that. I suggest you take a look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io)

There are several tutorials / github projects to get you started.

- [Modern Ember.js Application Workflow with Yeoman and Moch](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1249/modern-emberjs-application-workflow-with-yeoman-and-mocha)
- [introduction-to-ember-development](http://blog.embed.ly/post/46586649344/introduction-to-ember-development)

To answer your question regarding the templates:

Grunt has a [grunt-ember-templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates) plugin, capable of loading up individual handlebars template files and compiling them into a single JS (all handled by the grunt watcher).

the config below allows you to to split up your handlebars templates in app/templates while at runtime everything will be compiled into scripts/templates.js

```
ember_templates: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      templateName: function(sourceFile) {
        return sourceFile.replace(/app\/templates\//, '');
      }
    },
    files: {
      "<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates.js": ["<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.handlebars"]
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: while good, this doesnt answer the basic question of how to split the templates across multiple files.

Comment: See updated answer. I believe it covers separating the templates in files of their own. The workflow - partly delivered by grunt - is needed to give you a clean design-time view, while allowing for everything to compile properly for the runtime.